# Fastest and still safe way to exchange reference variables values

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Basically what i need is to be able to add items to List (or another collection) constantly, around 3000 times per second in one thread. And to get and remove all items from that list once per 2 seconds.

I don't like classic ways to do this like using concurrent collections or lock on something every time i need to access collection because it would be slower than i need.

What i'm trying to do is to have 2 collections, one for each thread, and to find a way to make a thread safe switch from one collection to another.

**Simplified** and not thread-safe example:

```
var listA = new List<int>();
var listB = new List<int>();

// method is called externally 3000 times per second
void ProducerThread(int a)
{      
    listA.Add(a)      
}
void ConsumerThread()
{
  while(true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    listB = Interlocked.Exchange(ref listA,listB);
    //... processing listB data
    // at this point when i'm done reading data
    // producer stil may add an item because ListA.Add is not atomic
    // correct me if i'm wrong
    listB.Clear();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make above code work as intended (to be thread safe) while having producer thread blocked as little as possible? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: I think your code would work. What guarantees are you looking for when you say "thread-safe" ?

Comment: You mean ListA.Add is an atomic operation? I'm afraid that Producer may already have a reference to list that i'm processing, so i can miss added value if it appears right before i clear the list.

Comment: No, Add is not atomic, I see your point now. You _could_ be pragmatic about it and do a short sleep after exchanging the variables.

Comment: I don't have much experience with something like this, but why not just: `ListB = ListA; ListA = new List<int>();`?  You could just lock ListA for the duration of the new assignment, which is very fast, and the old object is now referenced as ListB and no longer being added to.

Comment: Why are you using `List`? Have you considered using a `Dictionary<int,int>` so that you can customize the index per thread?

Comment: @japreiss - Good point.  I'd like to think `ListA = new List<int>()` would be fast enough to not need a lock, but I know better than to try it with something on this scale.

Comment: @driis or i can exchange variables before my regular Sleep(2000) but still not ideal :)

Comment: @TravisJ can you provide an example? I can't get your point.

Comment: Are you certain that using concurrent collections would not perform well? Adding 3,000 items per second is trivial. BlockingCollection will handle that just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start out by using a `BlockingCollection` or another `IProducerConsomerCollection` in System.Collections.Concurrent.  That is exactly what you have, a producer/consumer queue that is accessed from multiple threads.  Those collections are also heavily optimized for performance.  They don't use use a naive "lock the whole structure anytime anyone does any operation".  They are smart enough to avoid locking wherever possible using lock-free synchronization techniques, and when they do need to use critical sections they can minimize what needs to be locked on such that the structure can often be accessed concurrently despite a certain amount of locking.

Before I move from there to anything else I would use one of those collections and ensure that it is too slow.  If, after using that as your solution you have demonstrated that you are spending an unacceptable amount of time adding/removing items from the collection then you could consider investigating other solutions.

If, as I suspect will be the case, they perform quick enough, I'm sure you'll find that it makes writing the code *much* easier and clearer to read.

Comment: To be honest my opinion on blocking collections is based on another experience with them, i will test it on this task and accept your answer if it works fine

Comment: Well, answers and my research shows that there is no way to avoid lock on item Producer, so i'm gonna accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you just want to process new additions to `listA`, and that while you process these additions more additions are made.

```
var listA = new List<int>();
var dictA = new Dictionary<int,int>();

int rangeStart = 0;
int rangeEnd = 0;
bool protectRange = false;

// method is called externally 3000 times per second
void ProducerThread(int a)
{      
 listA.Add(a);
 dictA.Add(rangeEnd++,a);   
}
void ConsumerThread()
{
 while(true)
 {
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  int rangeInstance = rangeEnd;
  var listB = new List<int>();
  for( int start = rangeStart; start < rangeInstance; start++ ){
   listB.add(dictA[start]);
   rangeStart++;
  }
  //... processing listB data
  }
}
```

Comment: I also need to remove processed items (here comes the lock),
but good idea, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the table has a fixed maximum size, why use a List? You could also pre-set the list size.

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>(6000);
```

Now, I haven't really test the following, but I think it would do what you want:

```
int[] listA = new int[6000]; // 3000 time * 2 seconds
int i = 0;

// method is called externally 3000 times per second
void ProducerThread(int a)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(listA)) // If true, consumer is in cooldown.
    {
        listA[i] = a;
        i++;
        Monitor.Exit(listA);
    }
}

void ConsumerThread()
{
    Monitor.Enter(listA); // Acquire thread lock.

    while (true)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(listA, 2000); // Release thread lock for 2000ms, automaticly retake it after Producer released it.

        foreach (int a in listA) { } //Processing...

        listA = new int[6000];
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

You just need to be sure to have ConsumerThread run first, so it would queue itself and wait.

Comment: Can you give more information as to what you tried and what is not working right now?

Comment: I gave up on collections and used a StringBuilder so my data is processed at the time when new item is avalible, now i need to lock for a shorter period, it is when i get StringBuilders contents and clear it. Works fine.